# How should I use context manager to do a specific peewee model task?

Tags: peewee

I have implemented this code:

```
from peewee import Model, MySQLDatabase, CharField

from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager 
def get_database(): 
    return MySQLDatabase("films", user="root", host="localhost", port=3306)


class BasePeeweeModel(Model): 
    class Meta: database = db

class Films(BasePeeWeeModel): 
    code = CharField() 
    name = CharField()


try: 
    db.create_tables([Films]) 
except OperationalError: 
    print "Films able already exists"

with get_database() as db: 
     fobj = Films() 
     fobj.code = "LJ" 
     fobj.name = "Le Jatte" 
     fobj.save()
```

I want to be able to close db connection explicitly when task on a table is done!

Comment: Could you try formatting your code so it's readable? This is garbage

Comment: I posted from phone didn't had access to computer,  not even now

Comment: @coleifer I have fixed the indentation